# Exibir menu de acordo com permissão do usuário - Codeigniter - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!

Estou desenvolvendo um painel para criar e alterar permissão de usuário utilizando o plugin [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso funciona bem para mim, uma vez que utilizo uma tabela chamada `treeview` para montar a arvore do `jstree` e utilizo a tabela `tb_permission`, para determinar a permissão do usuário.

**treeview**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**tb_permission**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Relacionando o campo `name` da tabela `treeview` e o campo `function` da tabela `tb_permission`, eu verifico o estado do campo `allowed` da tabela `tb_permission` e se for `TRUE`, então o usuário tem permissão para tal função, se for igual a `FALSE`, o usuário não tem permissão.

> DÚVIDA

Minha dúvida surge no momento de exibir o MENU no sidebar, respeitando a permissão que o usuário tem.

Eu tentei adicionar um campo na tabela `tb_permission`, e criar a seguinte regra.

Primeiro obtenho o resultado do campo `parent_id` da tabela `tb_permission`, cujo o `type` seja igual a 2 e `allowed` seja igual a `TRUE`.

Depois, para cada `parent_id`, eu verifico quantos resultados obtive e se o valor for maior que zero, eu marco o campo `visible` como `TRUE`.

E o campo `visible`, eu iria utilizar como parâmetro para exibir o MENU no sidebar, em caso de `TRUE`

Mas além de não ter funcionado, acredito ter outras formas para se fazer.

```
// in test - check only type functions start
$parent = $this->db->select('parent_id')->from('tb_permission')->where('role_id', $role_id)->where('type', 2)->where('allowed', TRUE)->get()->result();
foreach($parent as $key => $item)
{
    //$this->db->where('menu_id', $item->parent_id)->where('role_id', $role_id)->update('tb_permission', ['visible' => TRUE]);
    $allowed     = $this->db->select('*')->from('tb_permission')->where('parent_id', $item->parent_id)->where('role_id', $role_id)->where('type !=', 0)->where('allowed', TRUE)->get()->num_rows();

    $visible     = $allowed > 0 ? TRUE : '';
    if ($visible)
        $this->db->where('menu_id', $item->parent_id)->where('type !=', 2)->where('role_id', $role_id)->update('tb_permission', ['visible' => TRUE]);
}
// in test - check only type functions end
```

**Sidebar**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheguei ao resultado esperado utilizando o seguinte:

Ainda acho que podem existir outras opções, se alguém puder divulgar, agradeço.

```
// in test - check only type functions start
$this->db->where('role_id', $role_id)->update('tb_permission', ['visible' => FALSE]);
parent = $this->db->select('parent_id')->from('tb_permission')->where('role_id', $role_id)->where('type !=', 0)->where('allowed', TRUE)->get()->result();
foreach($parent as $key => $item)
{            
     $allowed     = $this->db->select('*')->from('tb_permission')->where('parent_id', $item->parent_id)->where('role_id', $role_id)->where('type !=', 0)->where('allowed', TRUE)->get()->num_rows();

     $visible     = $allowed > 0 ? TRUE : '';
     if ($visible)
         $this->db->where('parent_id', $item->parent_id)->where('type', 0)->where('role_id', $role_id)->update('tb_permission', ['visible' => TRUE]);
         $this->db->where('parent_id', $item->parent_id)->where('type', 1)->where('role_id', $role_id)->where('allowed', TRUE)->update('tb_permission', ['visible' => TRUE]);
}
// in test - check only type functions end
```